# How to export and import all demo content of locally installed wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Recently I developed a wordpress theme and I want to put in themeorest. I need to export all of my demo content which are in localhost installed wordpress, So customers can easily make their website like as what is shown in demo theme.

Now I want to know how can I export that demo content and how to import theme easily?

The content such as `posts, categories, pages and of course media library`. WordPress's default import/exporter can't do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried some ways, but the easiest one was WordPress's export/import way. I simply exported the content using `All Content` option, then easily it can be used to import the content anywhere else.

But keep in mind the site we exporting it's content, **SHOULD** be an **online installation** and not be in localhost. In this way all media's URL will be a downloadable link, So content's all media will be downloaded and sit in their position in posts and pages.